# C# Form code and events not running while resizing form at runtime

Tags: c#, performance, forms, resize, runtime

I have tried doublebuffering the form - but while I am dragging the form sides or corners to resize it at runtime, the controls do not update and timer events are not firing, until I stop resizing the form with the mouse.

The form consists of a datagridview contained in a tabcontrol and some sounds playing. Everything runs fine unless I am resizing the window (form) at runtime.  This is not the end of the world, but just odd behaviour.

It is as though all events and handling are suspended on the form while the form is being resized, or the resizing event is using up all the processor (which it isn't).  Is there a way to force event handling while the user resizes the window form?

As a simple example, the form has a sound that is played every 500ms. If at runtime I drag the bottom corner or a side of the window to resize it, the sound is not played until I stop resizing the window (by either releasing mouse click, or not moving mouse).

Comment: you have cross thread issues, or you are doing everything in the same thread and blocking the thread. You need to separate the GUI functionality away from all other functionality. An MVVM (Model, View, ViewModel) pattern is more suitable in your case.

Comment: pretty much hit the nail on the head.  Resizing, while actually DOING the resizing, pretty much blocks the UI thread itself.  If the sound processing and timers, etc etc, are all also located on the same thread as the UI handling, then it will have the exact behavior that you have just described.

Comment: Resizing does **not** block the UI thread.  Windows pumps a modal message loop while the user is dragging the corner, it will get messages dispatched as normal.  Same basic idea as ShowDialog().  Timers keep ticking, painting still occurs.  How you got that borken is completely unclear from the question.

Comment: With all controls deleted from the form other then timer control that plays sound I get same issue.  While dragging the mouse around continually to resize the form, the timer event does not play the sound. It is as though resizing blocks the thread completely until the form size is stable (even if haven't released the mouse yet).

Comment: The resizing modal loop does not process timer tick events for some reason. Not sure if it is a matter of priorities.